# что значит условие продолжения цикла ;i < width-- size; опечатка?

Tags: c#, циклы

Язык C#. Кусок кода из книги Паласиоса про исскус.интелект в unity:
Создадим первый цикл для обхода конечной и исходной сеток:

```
for (i = 0; i < width-- size; i++) 
{
    for (j = 0; j < height-- size; j ++) 
    { 
        // дальнейшая реализация описывается ниже
    }
}
```

глупость какая-то...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в чем глупость заключается? в чем, в принципе,  вопрос? код правильно скопирован с книги?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский думаю в том, что `width-- size` неверно написано. Скорее всего там должен быть один символ `-`

Comment: @AGS17 именно поэтому мой вопрос про корректность скопированного кода. Вообще было бы интересно посмотреть и на скрин книги

Comment: Если книга в электронном виде - то скорее всего брак скана.... а если в бумажном - то это другой вопрос

Comment: скрин приложил.

Comment: Я бы с большим подозрением отнёсся к книге, в которой фигурируют записи `(int)(matrixLength - 1) / 2` и `int i, j, k, m`.

Answer (score 2):

Да. Это опечатка. Должен быть один "-", а не два.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/172976)

Comment: @cheops а каково решение вопроса на ваш взгляд?)

Comment: Возможно вас шокирую, но убрать один "-" в обоих циклах... `for (j = 0; j < height - size; j++)`